# How to delete products with no images

Tags: magento-1.7, product, magento-community

Is there away i can delete all product or at least find them in the backend interface ?

There must be away to export products with no images in dataflow and then import them back in but this time delete entries ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is **no way of deleting a product via Dataflow**. However, if you're comfortable running a script - the following standalone script will delete all products that don't have images<sup>*</sup>:

```
<?php
require('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->getSelect()
    ->joinLeft(
        array('_gallery_table' => $collection->getTable('catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery')),
        'e.entity_id = _gallery_table.entity_id',
        array()
    )
    ->where('_gallery_table.value IS NULL');
$collection->delete();
```

Do not run this on your production database without having tested it thoroughly first.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> Disclaimer: I am not responsible for any damage caused to your system. This code is untested. You alone are responsible for running code that you copied and pasted from a random person on the internet.</sub>

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892513/magento-get-products-without-images-using-collections

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486350/how-do-i-delete-data-using-collection-in-magento-orm

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely, Heres the logic:

Decide what type of product you are using
Run a mage.app (or other) Programatic code to run all the filters, then using the API delete process you will be able to delete the product based on ID

I use it all the time myself for updating product statuses, and disabling/deleting bundles that have 0 stock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a complete novice to magento, How do i do this ? Thanks Michael

Comment: All I can reccomend is reading into dealing with magento programatically and have a read through this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

I cant help much unfortunately if your new to magento, however the functions you are looking for are just a script away :) As soon as you write that one you can do allsorts!

Comment: If you would like a quick tutorial that can set you off please let me know and I'll be happy to write one out for you :)

Comment: Also good to familiarize yourself with working with collections. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento

Comment: Hi Adam, Yeah sure if you dont mind that would be a massive help for me :) thanks

Comment: okay michael sure, what products are you trying to find with no images? simple, bundle, configurable , etc? and also do you have a basic grasp of PHP e.g.
// <-- comments out code